# android clickable image carousel

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to implement an image carousel that opens up an activity whenever a particular image is clicked. Also the carousel should be dynamic in the sense that when a user clicks a particular marker in google maps, an image pertaining to that marker is displayed. Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a thread wich communicates with the UI main thread using the function RunOnUiThread(), so that this thread can change image and parameters of the Button/ImageButton/Image which is clicked.

Besides, if you want to let the map interact with it, just modify some global parameter of the Activity while pressing the marker, and use this parameter within the same thread which alrealdy modifies the image resource of your button.

Comment: Do you have any examples/code snippets that you can share?